# Refering to style is not working

Tags: android

I have written a Theme for my activity and for TextAppearance property i am referring to my own defined style .but its effect is not being shown

```
<style name="bigred" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">number</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>




    </style>

   <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
       <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/bigred</item>

   </style>
```

on assigning my activity as theme mytheme rest all properties are showing effect except TextAppearance.kindly update

Comment: so not even the color is changed?

Comment: no . i got the answer after some research. We can do it in two ways 1. you change textAppearance to textViewStyle and all textviews get the style bigred 2. you design a attribute in the theme called android:textAppearanceSmall and refer any style like <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@style/bigred</item> and it works since in themes.xml textViewStyle refers to textAppearanceSmall .i hope this clears . but it is difficult to find out what values work where .it is only when you apply you get the answer